# Unable to copy symbols from this device Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9.3

I got this popup when I try to run my application on 9.3 iOS device.
I read all the threads over the internet,tried to reset my phone,delete moduleCache and derivedData,reset Xcode, reset the privacy settings,I saw that may be a hard disk space issue,my iphone has 11 GB free space,my mac has 240 GB,I tried 5 different devices!
I tried everything but none work,it only reconstructs with 9.3 iOS devices.
Please help